# How to alert(date) with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying with this, but it is undignified.

In html.

```
 <BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="DOBpicker" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" DisplayType="TextBox"
  ValidationGroup="userRegistration" />
```

in jquery, I tried with this

```
 function btn()
{
  var date = $('#DOBpicker').val();
  alert(date);
}
```

**or**

```
function btn()
{
  var date = document.getElementById('DOBpicker').value;
  alert(date);
}
```

call this function on btn

```
<input id="test" type="button" value="go" onclick="btn()" />
```

But it undefined.

Comment: Seems like your BDP doesn't have value probably the reason it appears undefined

Comment: i dont see any `value=""` attribute, thats why its `undefined`

Comment: please edit the subject and fix misspelled jquree, users may search for subjects

Comment: Post your HTML output. Not the ASP.NET code, the actual HTML output after your browser renders the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `attr()` instead of `val()`. See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ftdf5/1/)
You have to have value otherwise it doesn't fire anything or just undefined. For instance I have added `value="Hello World"`

```
<BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="DOBpicker" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" DisplayType="TextBox"
  ValidationGroup="userRegistration" value="Hello World" /> 

var date = $('#DOBpicker').attr('value');

alert(date);​
```

Comment: but you have to have value there

Comment: What value plz explain.  use ur idea but still nothing,

Comment: Please see updated answer, let me know if its not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

It's a server side control, so you have to do something like $("[id*=DOBpicker]").val().
It's because the id ends up being longer in the DOM after it's rendered since ASP.Net appends the ids of its parents etc

```
You can also do $(#+'<%=DOBpicker.ID %>').val() since that gets the full id and not just the partial ID
```

Comment: Im use this but it shows nothing...! $("[id*=DOBpicker]").val()

Comment: Ok, it's possible that the underlying html element that it renders as doesn't have a value property. What does it look like in the markup  if you do view source? Target whatever element that holds the actual date in the DOM.